# Property 'intlTelInput' does not exist on type 'Window'

Tags: angular, angular6, angular7, intl-tel-input

I am working with angular7. I need International Telephone Input (https://intl-tel-input.com/) for my website.

So i used the following comment to install the CDN.

```
npm uninstall ng2-tel-input --save
```

After that i called the CSS and JS files in the angular.json

```
"styles": [
     "node_modules/intl-tel-input/build/css/intlTelInput.min.css",
      "src/styles.css"
],
"scripts": [
    "node_modules/intl-tel-input/build/js/utils.js",
    "node_modules/intl-tel-input/build/js/intlTelInput.min.js"
],
```

Added the input field for the telephone number in "contactform.compenent.html"

```
<input type="tel" class="form-control" value="" placeholder="Mobile number"
       id="telnumber-field" required>
```

And Added the script for the telephone area in "app.compenent.ts"

```
ngOnInit(){

jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ ) {   

    if(jQuery('#telnumber-field').length){
        var input = document.querySelector("#telnumber-field");
        window.intlTelInput(input, {
            preferredCountries: ['in'],
            separateDialCode: true
        });
    }       

}); }
```

But there is an error comes.

> ERROR in src/app/app.component.ts(65,11): error TS2339: Property 'intlTelInput' does not exist on type 'Window'.

Comment: try `window['intlTelInput']` or add it to the interface. `interface window { intlTelInput: any}`

Comment: Thanks for the help, keep up the good work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the time of typescript compilation **intlTelInput** object is not created on window object.change window type to `any` to skip property checking for window duration compilation. **intlTelInput** is visible once application is loaded in browser so application will work as expected.

```
  ngOnInit(){

   jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ ) {   

    if(jQuery('#telnumber-field').length){
        var input = document.querySelector("#telnumber-field");
       (<any>window).intlTelInput(input, {
            preferredCountries: ['in'],
            separateDialCode: true
        });
    }       

}); 
}
```

Comment: @MulammadNasir I just tried your solution and gives me same error as above. Angular 11.